# what is system load?

Tags: java

I have an application that loggs this value:

and calls it system load.
when I look at the log file this is a decimal number between 0 and 1.
oh and the operating system is linux.
I don't know what does it meen?

```
 ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean().getSystemLoadAverage();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the "load average" of a system is the average length of the CPU run queue over time. This is the same value reported by the `uptime` command.